# How to save and restore models in TensorFlow using noSQL database, like MongoDB?

Tags: python, tensorflow, nosql

I'm facing an issue with saving and restoring TensorFlow models.

By today I was using only saving to my filesystem, which was working well. As amount of models arose, I needed more sophisticated structure to handle and maintain my models.

My first shot was noSQL database, like MongoDB. Could anyone give me an advise, how to do it? Should I serialize it to JSON somehow?